# Datatable.net: Unable to get property 'aDataSort' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am getting an error saying

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'aDataSort' of undefined or null
>   reference
>   jquery.dataTables.min.js (65,437)

while running my following script in [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vcqsa235/19/#&togetherjs=Q2m6OTC5Nu)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var item = {};
    item["c1"] = "a" + i;
    item["c2"] = "b" + i;
    arr.push(item);
  };

  var dataSet = JSON.stringify(arr);
  console.log(dataSet);
    $('#example').DataTable({
    "data": dataSet
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting this error because you tried to instantiate the datatable twice - in my case, I had a data table with `genericDataTable` class and an id of `someDataTable` with (roughly) the following JS code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.genericDataTable').DataTable()

        ...Lots of other JS Code...

        $('#someDataTable).DataTable({
            "columns": [
                {
                    "title": "Name",
                    "data": "Name"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Street",
                    "data": "Street",
                },
                {
                    "title": "City",
                    "data": "City"
                },
                {
                    "title": "State",
                    "data": "State"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Actions",
                    "data": "Id"
                }
            ]
        });
    });
```